# sftp rename (mv) with wildcard

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp, rename

I use `sftp` to download files from a server nightly. Presently I batch download them with this sftp script:

chmod 444 /home/sftpserveruser/*.HL7
get MTB*.HL7 /data/hl7/downloads/mtb/

I'd like to be able to move them with the same sftp script, but am running into issues. I don't know the filename ahead of time.

Wildcards don't appear to work:

> sftp> rename MTB*.HL7 HL7_archive/
>
> Couldn't rename file "/home/sftpserveruser/MTB*.HL7" to
> "/home/sftpserveruser/HL7_archive/": No such file or directory sftp>

And if moving to another folder, rename requires a filename for the destination folder as well

> sftp> rename MTB20230801.HL7 HL7_archive/
>
> Couldn't rename file "/home/sftpserveruser/MTB*.HL7" to
> "/home/sftpserveruser/HL7_archive/": No such file or directory sftp>

This works, but I'm unsure how to get the filename with sftp:

> sftp> rename MTB20230801.HL7 HL7_archive/MTB20230801.HL7
>
> sftp>

Is there a better way of doing this outside of mixing sftp + bash scripting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`lftp`](https://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html) command is much more versatile and available in most Linux distributions. It supports multiple protocols. For SFTP, use `lftp sftp://user@host`. Since it's using the same backend, it follows all of SSH configuration in `~/.ssh` just as the `sftp` command. It includes an `mmv` command to move (only move, not change actual name in any way) multiple files to a target directory. It will allow wildcards to select these files.

```shell
$ lftp -c 'help mmv'
Usage: mmv [OPTS] <files> <target-dir>
Move <files> to <target-directory> with wildcard expansion
 -O <dir>  specifies the target directory (alternative way)
```

Scripting with `lftp` should be easier than with `sftp`.

Comment: Migrated to `lftp`, things are working much better now. Thanks.